# Csv loading from windows error

Tags: java, windows, csv, attachment

Using my api user can upload csv file only.I will parse this csv data using java as

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.*;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Upload {
parseAndLoad(MultipartBody body) {
Attachment atc = body.getAttachment("file");
final ContentDisposition disposition = atc.getContentDisposition();
    final String filename = disposition.getFilename();
    String fileExt = ContentUtils.getFileExtention(filename);
    if (!"csv".equalsIgnoreCase(fileExt)) {
System.out.println("Upload only csv file");      
    }
}
}
```

This is working fine.But when I am uploading any csv file from windows system, it automatically got converted to xls.
How to handle this case?

Comment: how do you know that it is "converted" to XLS?

Comment: Maybe Excel is the default application for opening CSV files ?

Comment: If I download any csv file in windows, it got converted to another format.If I want to test with "test.csv" with this api, it is not working